# Inconsistent behaviour of Office.Body.setAsync

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

The `Office.Body.setAsync` docs state the following errors:

> - DataExceedsMaximumSize: The data parameter is longer than 1,000,000 characters.
> - InvalidFormatError: The options.coercionType parameter is set to Office.CoercionType.Html and the message body is in plain text.

However, the `InvalidFormatError` is never thrown. In fact, the behaviour is inconsistent across platforms.

Consider the following scenario: The user has set the Content Type to Plain Text, and the setAsync() method is passed `Office.CoercionType.Html` as a parameter.

1. On Windows, the Content Type **changes** to `Office.CoercionType.Html` and the content is set accordingly.
2. On Outlook on the Web, the Content Type remains **unchanged**. The content is set in plain text.

Is there any way of changing the Content Type on Outlook on the Web as well?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this inconsistency, this information has been passed to the appropriate product team and is currently being investigated. We will update the issue when we have more information.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT What is the expected behaviour for all platforms?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT any update on the same?

Comment: The expected behavior on all platforms is what we have documented online. We are currently reviewing all our platforms to determine the best approach here so that we can have a better developer exeprience.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the discrepancy in the API. We acknowledge this and have opened a work item in our backlog to address it however don't have timelines to share at this time for fixing this. That said, to avoid getting into such a condition, we recommend using the getTypeAsync API on the body first, to get the coercion type, and then passing that to the setBody API. Also, currently the feature to set coercion type on the message is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.